# How to prevent console output mixed with maven output?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I don't know how to properly describe this problem. My output "Hello World" is mixed up with the maven build output. I marked it with **. Pls, look at codeblock. I am having a maven project with Java 19. My IDE is IntelliJ Ultimate 2022.3. And here are pictures of my settings. How can I make Intellij only do the output of the program?

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\java.exe" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=E:\HDA\Distributed Systems\vs-projekt" "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=60937:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2022.2.3 "-Dexec.workingdir=E:/HDA/Distributed Systems/vs-projekt" "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath Main" "-Dexec.executable=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\java.exe" exec:exec
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< org.hda:Mo5x-Burchard >------------------------
[INFO] Building Mo5x-Burchard 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec (default-cli) @ Mo5x-Burchard ---
**Hello World**
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.514 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-01T16:50:37+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Does it maybe has something to do with my `pom.xml`?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>org.hda</groupId>
        <artifactId>Mo5x-Burchard</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>
    
        <build>
            <defaultGoal>compile</defaultGoal>
            <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
                <plugins>
                    <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.1</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.7.1</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

[image: Maven Build Setting]
[image: Project Run Config]
[image: Java Compiler Setting]

Comment: Make sure Run is not delegated to Maven: https://i.imgur.com/HpeUaUE.png. Use Application configuration to start your app per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Run is [not delegated to Maven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emNsQ.png).

Use [Application configuration to start your app](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html).